# Disappearing keyboard shortcut in Outlook 2011 for Mac

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2011

I move a lot of messages outside of my inbox. Naturally I try to use keyboard shortcuts where possible to help save time, and Outlook for Mac has a really great UI flow to move messages quickly.

The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. If you select a message, initial the keyboard shortcut, you get presented with a Google-suggest style window to quickly find what folder you need to move your messages to. It's fantastic.

Except when the keyboard shortcut decides to dynamically remove itself from the current run of Outlook.

If you click on Message->Move in the menubar, you'll see that the keyboard shortcut is displayed next to the command. However for some reason, I haven't figured out the pattern, the keyboard short cut will just disappear by itself. This forces me to have to restart Outlook, which we all know is very annoying.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening? Is it a bug? A feature? both? I need to prevent the shortcut from disappearing.

I'm running Snow Leopard and Outlook 14.1.0 (110310).

UPDATE: Just realized that if I switch views in Outlook using keyboard shortcuts (command+2 to go to Calendar) then go back, the move shortcut key disappears in the Mail view. This doesn't happen if I use the mouse to switch views. I suppose it's a bug with Outlook itself. Oh well.

Comment: This occurs for me regardless of how I switch views, and restarting Outlook doesn't solve the problem. Running Snow Leopard and Outlook 2011 14.1.2.